# Is there a way to generate an ASP.NET 4 server using Swagger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Looking at the output targets for swagger-codegen, I can only see options to generate `aspnetcore`- and `aspnet5` servers, the latter being deprecated. Is there a way to generate a server that results in an ASP.NET 4 solution, preferably in a way that would allow me to "include" the generated code in an existing MVC application?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try Swagger Codegen v2.1.6 stable release: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.1.6 to generate `aspnet5` server stub.

To make it compatible with ASP.NET4 solution, you can try customizing the templates and use the `-t` options with the templates customized to work with ASP.NET4

Comment: I wonder why there isn't a generator for "ordinary" ASP.NET ... it seems unlikely that everyone is shifting to .NET core while it is still in its infancy ...

Comment: We've not seen any request for a ASP.NET4 generator. Please feel free to open an issue for tracking to see if anyone from the community has a work-in-progress/beta generator for that: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new.